# Recode over a range in python

Tags: python, numpy, range, recode

I want to recode the numeric values to categories 1 to 4. When the last condition is run it turns all the previous recoded values into 4. How can I recode over a range of values in python?

```
df2['col1'] = np.where(df2['col1'] < -1.27, 1,df2['col1'].values)
df2['col1'] = np.where(  (df2['col1'] >= -1.27) & (df2['col1'] < -0.74), 2,df2['col1'].values )
df2['col1'] = np.where(  (df2['col1'] >= -0.74) & (df2['col1'] < -0.075), 3,df2['col1'].values)
df2['col1'] = np.where((df2['col1'] >= -0.075) , 4, df2['col1'].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the last comparison excludes the values you've already assigned.

```
df2[df2['col1'] < -1.27] = 1
df2[(df2['col1'] >= -1.27) & (df2['col1'] < -0.74)] = 2
df2[(df2['col1'] >= -0.74) & (df2['col1'] < -0.075)] = 3
df2[(df2['col1'] >= -0.075) & (df2['col1'] < 1)] = 4
```

If your data actually contains positive values, then you will have to assign to a new column.

Comment: the variable values run from -3 to 3.

Comment: Well, then, you can't do this in place.  You MUST create your categories in a new column.  Otherwise, there's no way to tell the difference between a value "2" and a category "2".